# Using 'contains check' via regex

Tags: java, regex

I'd like some help with a regex please. Basically, i am looking for something that would match anything but something that contains the key word.

Regex should match anything that does not contain "bar"

```
    String i1 = "foo";
    String i2 = "foo bar";
    String i3 = "bar foo";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\(!(bar)\\).*");

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(i1);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // false, should be true

    matcher = p.matcher(i2);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // false

    matcher = p.matcher(i3);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // false
```

How can regex be changed to properly do the contains check?

Comment: see this similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:(?!bar).)*$
```

Is exactly what you are looking for unless I am mistaken.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use `^(?!.*bar)`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just match you keyword and negate the match?
as in:

```
String i1 = "foo";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\((bar)\\).*");

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(i1);
System.out.println(!matcher.matches());
```

Otherwise I would look about lookahead/lookbehind operators...